# My spam flag is declined, even though the culprit is deleted

Tags: support

I visited this answer: "[Can Office Network printed Documents be read by network admins?](https://superuser.com/questions/860585/can-office-network-printed-documents-be-read-by-network-admins/1181125#1181125)" It was a rant about how the world is Orwellian and is going to hell. So, I flagged it as spam.

Now, my dashboard tells me that "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it". But it seems a moderator has deleted it nevertheless.

If it was not spam, why was it deleted? If it was spam, why is my flag rejected?

Comment: It wasn't spam, it was just utter gibberish. Spam is unsolicited or unwanted advertising and there was no sign of any advertising in the answer you flagged.

Comment: @Mokubai If your email provider had gone forward with your definition of spam, your email account would have been in serious trouble.

Comment: The text of the spam flag you selected states: "Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation" so as far as this site is concerned that is what we expect spam flags to be used for.

Comment: It also reads "spam" in boldface. Maybe I should file a request to change "spam" to "promotional"?

Comment: Some of the answers on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287278/how-do-we-stop-users-from-using-the-spam-flag-when-there-is-no-promotion-of-a discuss that option, but for the most part it falls back to the fact that our definition of spam is much more strict than just "vague rubbish". http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243345/can-the-spam-flag-description-be-reworded shows a case for what the community believes should be done in the case of gibberish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was *terrible* but there's additional penalties with spam flags. As such, I didn't want to hit it with the full spam flag penalty *but* wanted the answer gone.

It happens sometimes with spam flags.

A safe bet here might be NAA flags.

Comment: What are the penalties?

Comment: -100 reputation